# Changing the hover behavior of dynamically generated classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

My goal is to design an e-commerce storefront with tile design, where the thumbnail of an item is shown, then upon hover, the item name is shows above it. Similar to [this](http://www.flatguitars.com/gallery), except that it slides up on `hover` instead of simply appearing.

The main problem is that we're using an e-commerce storefront solution with a prepackaged template for the item display, where all HTML is autogenerated, and all items have a css class with no css ID.

Here's the HTML, with unneeded code edited out

```
<td class="hoverClass">
    <--Edited out code-->
        <table class="otherClass" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="height: 158px; width: 190px;">
          <edited out>
        </table>
        <table class="appearClass" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <edited out>
        </table>
</td>
```

My goal is to hover of `.hoverClass` and `.appearClass` appears over it. I included `.otherClass` because in my research it tended to be 2 divs on the same level that could slide toggle, not a parent and child Div My plan was to use Jquery `slideToggle` so I tried dynamically adding IDs to the classes.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hoverClass");
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("appearClass");
var thumbArray = [];
var footArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    thumbArray.push("catThumb" + i);
    footArray.push("catFoot" + i);
    x[i].id = thumbArray[i];
    y[i].id = footArray[i];
}
for(var j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
{
    $("#" + thumbArray[j]).hover(function(){
        $("#" + footArray[j]).slideToggle();
    });
}
</script>
```

What occurs is that all the elements have their IDs created, but all those custom hover IDs have their hover bonded to the last `appearClass` element. In other words, if I have 10 items and I run this code, hovering over items 1 through 10 only causes the slide on item 10.

How can I get the hover IDs to bond with its instance of appear ID?

Comment: That's because a closure issue in handler but why don't you just use a class instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get  **footArray[j]** value when you hover the item If you want desire output use this

```
for(var j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
{
    $("#" + thumbArray[j]).hover(function(){
        $("#"+this.id.replace("catThumb","catFoot")).slideToggle();
    });
}
```

If Those are dynamic class you can use like this

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave","[class^=catThumb]",function(){

  $("[class^=catFoot]").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: This one worked! Thank you so much! SO won't let me select as an answer for a few more minutes.

Comment: K where is catThumb,catFoot elements ,what is the relation b/w those  ?

Comment: Those are the dynamically generated IDs.

Comment: No `hover` isn't a event, you cannot delegate it. Use `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` instead

Answer (score 2):

Don't use dynamic IDs, use the classes instead:

```
$('.hoverClass').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.appearClass').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: @9Deuce You should provide all relevant HTML mrkup in question (not edited) and maybe a jsFiddle. This kind of solution would be better than using useless IDs

Comment: @A.Wolff The useless ID method has worked. Balachandran's first answer worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little more jQuery-ish, but I don't think you need to add id's to them (unless you need to for something else, then I'll update my answer).

```
<script>
var hovers = $(".hoverClass");

$.each(hovers, function() {
    $(this).hover(function(){
        var appear = $(this).find(".appearClass");
        appear.slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did not achieve the desired result. Thanks though.

Comment: @9Deuce no problem. Glad you found a solution.